# How to test linked list ADT?

Tags: adt

I am trying to test the linked list ADT which I have created. However, whenever I try to test my ADT, it isn't creating a list, I don't understand why?, Currently, we are using the dummyNode method rather than having the first element as the head of the list. Does it have something to do with my ADT?

```
node*createList()
{
    node*dummyNode; 

    dummyNode = malloc(sizeof(node)*101);

    dummyNode->next = NULL;

    return dummyNode; 
}
node*addFront(node*list, int toBeAdded)
{
    node*newNode;

    newNode = initNode(toBeAdded);

    newNode->next = list->next;

    list->next = newNode;

    return newNode;
}

void printList(node*theHead)
{
    node*currentPosition;

    currentPosition = theHead->next;

    while(currentPosition != NULL)
    {
        printf("This is the value of the current node : %d\n",currentPosition->nodeValue);
        currentPosition= currentPosition->next;
    }
}
node*initNode(int getValue)
{
    node*newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node)*101);

    newNode->nodeValue = getValue;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
void destroyList(node*theList)
{
    node*temp;

    theList->nodeValue = 0;

    while(theList->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = theList->next;
        free(theList);
        theList=temp;
    }
}
node*removeFromFront(node*theList) 
{
    node*temp;

    if(theList==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    temp=theList->next;

    theList->next=NULL;

    return temp;
}
int listLength(node*theHead)
{
    int length;

    length=0;

    while(theHead != NULL)
    {
        length++;
        theHead = theHead ->next;
    }
    return length;
}

and this is my test.c 
node*testData;
int length,i;
int myArray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

testData = createList();

length = listLength(testData);

for(i=0; i<length; i++)
{
    testData = addFront(testData, myArray[i]);
    printList(testData);

}
This is the struct 
 struct listNode 
{
    int nodeValue;
    struct listNode * next;
};

typedef struct listNode node;

node*createList();
node*addFront(node*theHead, int toBeAdded);
void printList(node*theHead);
node*initNode(int getValue);
void destroyList(node*theList);
node*removeFromFront(node*theList);
int listLength(node*theHead);
```

Comment: What does the initNode() function do? Also, what does the struct look like

Comment: I posted the struct and the initNode gets the initial element

Comment: Oops, the scroll wasnt working for some reason first time I loaded

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your tests one line at a time with pen and paper? Boxes and Arrows is an incredibly effective way to trace through a Linked List ADT

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet, but I will. However, I'm confused about the dummy node. When I create a list, it creates a dummy node and I think that is why the list is not being created. Is it the way I have implemented the ADT?

Comment: notice that in your test.c your run the loop of adding elements to the list up to the list length which is initially empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implemention is fine, the problem is your test.c

First, as noted before, change your allocation to this:

```
malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Next your test.c should be:

```
int main() {

node*testData;
int length,i;
int myArray[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

testData = createList();

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    addFront(testData, myArray[i]);
}

printList(testData);

destroyList(testData);

return 0;
}
```

This should print the expected result:

```
This is the value of the current node : 5
This is the value of the current node : 4
This is the value of the current node : 3
This is the value of the current node : 2
This is the value of the current node : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Trace through your functions using the test you've created.  You should discover a problem within your addToFront() function. Primarily with the line  `newNode->next = list->next;` .

Once you've discovered the issue with that and resolved it, try your tests again.  Your pointer logic is just a bit off.

Also, as an aside, malloc(sizeof(node)*101) is allocating more memory than needed, its much better to just malloc(sizeof(node))

Comment: Just make sure to check everything, that was really only messing up the order of your list, as @akarbi said above, there are some problems with your test suite